# Why I am getting this output when run readelf -s

Tags: linux-kernel, elf, objcopy

I have Linux Kernel with me and trying to generate ELF Header on it using objcopy tool,
Below is the first step

```
     objcopy -I binary -B i386 -O elf32-i386 --rename-section .data=.text linux_kernel.bin  main.o
```

And after this I wanted to read symbol table using readelf -s main.o ,but getting strange symbols, below is output

```
   Symbol table '.symtab' contains 5 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
 0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
 1: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
 2: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _binary_linux_kernel_bin_
 3: 004df650     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _binary_linux_kernel_bin_
 4: 004df650     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _binary_linux_kernel_bin_
```

Now should be able to see symbols like

```
_binary_linux_kernel_bin_start
_binary_linux_kernel_bin__end
_binary_linux_kernel_bin_size
```

Can any body let me know where I am doing wrong?? or is it expected one??

Why I wanted to see proper symbol because have to do something like below one

```
 --entry_point=_binary_linux_kernel_bin_start
```

Comment: Are you sure the output isn't just truncated? Have you tried in a larger terminal window?

Comment: Yes I can see whole big line down after this particular ouput

Comment: It is not the terminal that is truncating.  It is `readelf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simply that the string is too long and `readelf` is truncating.  Try `objdump -x main.o`.

Comment: 'Thanks Bills "objdump -x main.o" shows me "_binary_linux_kernel_bin_start" but just one more wanted to know is _binary_linux_kernel_bin_start=_start ??

Comment: It will be 'zero'.  The way the `objcopy` works is you can create a binary and put it in to an object.  The `_start` will not be the kernel start address.  If you link the 'main.o' with some other object and create a final elf, then `_binary_linux_kernel_bin_start` will be the address in the image.  You can not create linux load address from the binary.  That information is gone.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `readelf -W -s main.o` command, where the `-W` tells `readelf` not to truncate the output to 80-character width.